# why I can't write an Abstract with 3 languages Arabic, french and English

Tags: pdftex, arabic, abstract

I'm writing my master thesis with Latex, so I'm trying to write an abstract with arabic, french and english, I'm using *pdfLatex* engine, here's the main.tex :

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,parskip=half,appendixprefix,headsepline,numbers=noenddot, openany]{scrbook}

\input{Structure_memoire}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{frontmatter/page de garde}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newcommand{\disableopenany}{%
%   \@openrighttrue%
%}                                                               document
%\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}
\begin{spacing}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\{Dédicaces}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
%\include{dedicaces}
%\include{remerciment}
\include{frontmatter/remerciement}
%\include{frontmatter/Abstract}

\newpage
\null
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\{abstract}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire} 

\tableofcontents

\include{frontmatter/listdesabbr}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\chapter*{Remerciements}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire} 
%\tableofcontents

\let\oldnumberline\numberline%

\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoftables

\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures
%{\listoffigures \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage \listoftables}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{headings}
\end{spacing} 
%%%%%%%%%\Corps\%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\enableopenany
\include{mainmatter/intro}

%\enableopenany
\include{mainmatter/chap1}
%\enableopenany
\include{mainmatter/chap2}
%\enableopenany
\include{mainmatter/chap3}

\include{mainmatter/chap4}

\include{mainmatter/conclusion}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\makeatother
%\include{Perspectives}
%\include{bibliography}
\begin{spacing}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference/myref}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

and this is all the pachages that I'm using:

> \usepackage{float} %Pour dire que les "tables" sont des "tableaux"
> \usepackage[tablename=Tableau]{caption} \usepackage{array}
> \usepackage{minitoc} \usepackage{shorttoc}
> \usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor} \usepackage{tikz}
> \usepackage{framed} \usepackage{lettrine}
> \usepackage[inline]{enumitem} \usepackage{arabtex}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[arabic]{babel}
>
> \usepackage{subcaption} \usepackage{setspace}
> \usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
> \usepackage[kerning=true,spacing=true,tracking=true]{microtype}
> \usepackage{enumitem} \usepackage{pdfpages} \usepackage{etoolbox}

so any solutions please ?

Comment: Do you think you could condense your code into a self-contained MWE that reproduces your bug? Some of your files are missing, and you don’t say what output you want or what you’re getting.

Comment: Not exactly related to your question, but I gather from the information in your preamble that your document is mainly in french, so I would suggest giving `babel` the set of options: `[arabic, english,main=french]`. That way, your floats will already have the proper french names and you wouldn't to define them using `float`. That would also give you the option of using `otherlanguage` environments for the english and arabic abstract, which will be useful for linebreaks and punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

`scrbook` doesn't have an `abstract` environment. So you could define your own one, like

```
\newenvironment{abstract}[1] % title
{%
  \renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}%
  \section*{#1}%
  \begin{quote}%
}
{\end{quote}}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\begin{abstract}{Résumé}
  French abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}{Abstract}
  English abstract
\end{abstract}

% Don't know Arabic

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
```

[image]